# Why Normality is considered as an important assumption for dependent and independent variables?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, normal-distribution

While going through one kernel on Kaggle regarding Regression in that it was mentioned that the data should look like a normal distribution. But I am not getting why? 
I know this question might be very basic But please help me to understand this concept.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: That rather looks like a question for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @stats0007 I will post there as well. I will look here as well if someone answers this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regression models make a number of assumptions, one of which is normality. When this assumption is violated then your p-values and confidence intervals around your coefficient estimate could be wrong, leading to incorrect conclusions about the statistical significance of your predictors

However, a common misconception is that the data (i.e. the variables/predictors) needs to be normally distributed, but this is not true. These models don't make any assumptions about the distribution of predictors.

For example, imagine a case where you have a binary predictor in regression (Male/Female; Slow/Fast etc.) - it would be impossible for this variable to be normally distributed and yet it is still a valid predictor to use in a regression model. The normality assumption actually refers to the distribution of the residuals, not the predictors themselves

Comment: Further, the normality assumption on the residuals is only required for inferential purposes such as p-values, confidence intervals and prediction intervals. The estimated coefficients require far weaker assumptions.